# Can't write from-oracle pandas datafrime to parquet

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

my litle from-oracle-pipeline has to write pandas dataframe to parquet file.
I use pyarrow lib for this:

```
df2 = pyarrow.Table.from_pandas(df) 
pyarrow.parquet.write_table(df, 'file.parquet', compression = 'BROTLI')
```

But result is:

'Could not convert {} with type cx_Oracle.LOB: did not recognize Python value type when inferring an Arrow data type', 'Conversion failed for column MY_JSON_FIELD with type object') .

How to fix problem? how to write big text field to paquet?o

Comment: You need to ensure to convert the `type cx_Oracle.LOB` to normal Python byte or str objects, and then converting to arrow will work as expected.